# AWS MediaConvert hrdBufferSize error when uploading 2160p content

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, codec, aws-media-convert

I've been using the "Video on Demand on AWS" CloudFormation template for a couple of years with very few issues, but lately when uploading 4K video (.mp4) to the pipeline (such as from an iPhone), I receive the following error:

```
BadRequestException: /outputGroups/0/outputs/2/videoDescription/codecSettings/h265Settings/hrdBufferSize: Should be less than or equal to 27500000
```

I've found references to this property in the MediaConvert documentation, but without much explanation for what it is, or where I should specify something other than the default.

I've been through every Lambda function created by the pipeline and cannot find reference to this property either. I'm using MediaConvert system defaults passed in to the encode Lambda (e.g. System-Hevc_2160p_25fps_15mbps, I can provide a full list if it's pertinent)

Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears you have encountered a bug in the preset for System-Hevc_2160p_25fps_15mpbs. We are working to update the preset, but I do not have a date for when it will be corrected.

For additional information on specific bitrate range and buffer size limitation please refer to the ISO/IEC specifications. For h264, you can find the limitations in the h264 specifications (ISO/IEC 14496-10) table A-1 - Level Limits.

Comment: Thanks for the information Karen, appreciate it. Do you think that when the preset is amended in the future this problem should remedy itself then?

Comment: Hi Dan. Once the preset has been corrected, you should be able to use the template as you had previously.